# Magento [There has been an error processing your request]

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cms

Suddenly the website homepage started showing the "There has been an error processing your request". When I have tried to login in the admin panel. The login page open but after submitting password there is same error.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to open the record number but don't understand.

Please help.

Comment: Post the entire report, not just the tail.  `cat 1277109061901`.

Answer (score 0):

Change file name :

**\pub\errors\local.xml.sample** to **\pub\errors\local.xml**

To see what error is happening.